# Postgres inner query performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, group-by

I have a table which I need to select from everything with this rule:

```
id = 4524522000143 and validPoint = true
and date >  (max(date)- interval '12 month')
-- the max date, is the max date for this id
```

Explaining the rule: I have to get all registers and count them, they must be at least 1 year old from the newest register.

This is my actual query:

```
WITH points as (
    select 1 as ct from base_faturamento_mensal
    where id = 4524522000143 and validPoint = true
    group by id,date
    having date >  (max(date)- interval '12 month')
)  select sum(ct) from points
```

Is there a more efficient way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your query is using the trick with including an unaggregated column within `HAVING` clause but I don't find it particularly bad. It seems fine, but without the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>` output I can't say much more.

One thing to do is you can get rid of the CTE and use `count(*)` within the same query instead of returning `1` and then running a `sum` on it afterwards.

```
select count(*) as ct
from base_faturamento_mensal
where id = 4524522000143 
  and validPoint = true
group by id, date
having date > max(date) - interval '12 months'
```